# C# record - using with keyword to modify properties

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

I recently ran into the `record` keyword in C#, I'm able to create a an instance of a record and modify it both by assigning a value regularly and both by using the keyword `with`.

Is there any difference between the two ways, when should one use `with`?

```
public record Car{

    public Car(string name, int age){
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}


public static void Main()
{
    var car = new Car("Reno", 15);
    car.Name = "Honda";
    
    Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
    
    car = car with {Name = "BMW"};
    
    Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the main reasons for records introduction in C# - make it easier to create immutable [data models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record). `with` functionality was created to provide an easy to use syntax to create a copy of immutable instance with changed properties. So `car = car with {Name = "BMW"};` actually does not modify the original instance (note that `record`'s are reference types, unless they are declared as `record struct`'s) but creates a new one and assigns it to the variable.
The difference can easily be seen with the following code:

```
var car = new Car("Reno", 15);
var car2 = car;
car.Name = "Honda";

Console.WriteLine(car.Name);  // "Honda"
Console.WriteLine(car2.Name); // "Honda"

car = car with {Name = "BMW"};

Console.WriteLine(car.Name);  // "BMW" 
Console.WriteLine(car2.Name); // "Honda"
```

Also couple of notes:

- it is recommended to use autoproperties instead of fields, i.e.:

```cs
public record Car
{
    public Car(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; };
    public int Age { get; set; };
}
```

- in case you need immutable data `record`s provide neat syntax which automatically generates constructor and init-only properties:

```
public record Car(string Name, int Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. The difference is that `with` creates a copy of the record. According to the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#with-expression):

> A `with` expression allows for "non-destructive mutation", designed to produce a copy of the receiver expression with modifications in assignments in the `member_initializer_list`.
>
> [...]
>
> First, receiver's "clone" method (specified above) is invoked and its result is converted to the receiver's type. Then, each `member_initializer` is processed the same way as an assignment to a field or property access of the result of the conversion.

So there is an extra step of copying the record if you use `with`.

See also the decompiled C# code on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACATgUwMYHtkBNEGEBDZAb1lkUsQQOIAoQIAGRAO0IFtUAaRAS1YAXRIQDmqAJRkYVWYgBynVIgC8bJQG4KcygEFxqkeK0yqAX3KnKNRi0VcTsmgOH7UJizFjhqEAOyI0uBgsNKyAG7EiOhRaqyoAO60yHQARABKqKyYqbwQAKwSjlQxyAB09spqqQASmKw4hKnFlNqtVr4AnHSlFUpFbYiDpYYjCXyCABaBlYapAEIAsgDqqWYtQx2M3b2VAzCeZkA===). Notice the `<Clone>` call before setting `car2.Name = "BMW"`, which does not happen when setting `car.Name = "Honda"`.

```
Car car = new Car("Reno", 15);
car.Name = "Honda";
Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
Car car2 = car.<Clone>$();
car2.Name = "BMW";
Console.WriteLine(car2.Name);
```