# How to Locally modify shared objects in Tasks to prevent Side Effects

Tags: c#, concurrency, task, side-effects, shared-resource

I have an object shared between concurrent Tasks. It's for creating different JSONs using the same set of properties. Here is a simplified example of its class: (I call it builder but it's not really following the builder pattern.)

```
class Builder {
    public string part1;
    public string part2;
    //More parts...

    public JSON BuildA(){
        return new Serialize(TypeA({"1": part1, "2": part2}));
    }
    public JSON BuildB(){
        return new Serialize(TypeB(part1.ToString(), part2 + part3));
    }
    //More Building methods
}
```

The parts are initialized before the builder being passed to the tasks. The problem is in some tasks I might want to locally overwrite one or two properties before building. Since the builder is shared between tasks, these changes causes unwanted side effects on other tasks.

```
Task.Run(() => MethodA(builder));
Task.Run(() => MethodB(builder));
Task.Run(() => MethodC(builder));

Response MethodA(Builder builder){
    builder.SetPart1(10);
    builder.SetPart16(false);
    JSON = builder.BuildC();
    //do http request stuffs
}
```

Besides deep cloning my builder, is another way to make change or overwrites to an shared object while preventing side effect?

Note: I'm using .NET 6

---

For now, what I can think of is passing a builder object as local property overwrites and modify every single getter and places that invokes the getter:

```
JSON = builder.Build(new Builder(){part1=10, part16=false})

class Builder {
    public string getPart1(Builder overwrites){
        return overwrites.part1 ?? part1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Besides deep cloning my builder, is another way to make change to an shared object while preventing side effect?

Basically no. But you can ease the life by switching to [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) which allow easier creation and management of immutable data-types:

```
var builder = new Builder("one", "two");
var newBuilder = builder with { Part1 = "new" };

record Builder(string Part1, string Part2) {
    public JSON BuildA(){
        return new Serialize(TypeA({"1": part1, "2": part2}));
    }
    public JSON BuildB(){
        return new Serialize(TypeB(part1.ToString(), part2 + part3));
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. [`with` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) still shallow-copies properties so use records for nested data types.
2. For "optional" properties you can use `init`-only properties:

   ```
   var newBuilder = builder with { Part1 = "new", I = 5};

   record Builder(string Part1, string Part2) {
       public int I { get; init; }
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. [C# record - using with keyword to modify properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69529337/2501279)

Comment: I just noticed shallow copying the object is sufficient since I'm mutating only non-nested data types!  In this case, `builder with { Part1 = "new", I = 5}` couldn't be more perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @SyndRain - was glad to help!